# Preventing Zalgo text from spanning outside the box

Tags: feature-request, markdown, posts

When an extraneous amount of Zalgo text is posted, it will span outside the box and prevent others from seeing the posts above/below it.  Zalgo text should be contained inside the box so that it doesn't cover up anything else, such as the flag button; it should never be difficult to flag a post and Zalgo text is valid in the Formatting Sandbox, but especially in comments, can be annoying.

## Demonstration of the issue

Reveal the spoiler to reveal the issue:

> S̴̡̡̨̡̧̡̨̡̢̛̮̞̺̝̩͙̤͈̼̻̪̰͎̥̙̻̰͉̣͉̹̻͔̙̖̦̭̖̟͈̩̪̮̰̘͎̭̬̲̥͉̗̞̳͓̬̖̜̺̟̱̺̮̥̫͖̜̠͍̯̱̲̹̠̟͎̞͓̪̼̬̬̯͖͍͚̬̯̺̞̺͇̤̘̻̲͎̅̐̒̇̂͂̾̿̿̑̑̅̉̇̔̉͆̌́̇͘͘̕͘͘͜͜͜͝͠͝͠͠ͅͅͅe̴̢̢̡̠͎̞̰͔̻̳̦̞̘̼̞͓̺̟̦̙̥̱͖̮̳̮̺͚͙̝̝͉̝̖̖̺̠̞̲͖̦̺̰͉̦̠̫͈̣͔̱̘̥̳̫̲̼̼̠͖͑́̉̔͋̈̾̎̀̈̃͆͂̍̄̿́͆͊͐́̕͜͜͜͝ͅr̷̡̨̡̡̡̨̨̢̧̧̧̧̨̧̡̡̡̙̟̰̟̺͇̬̻̖̯̭̣̹̻̯͔̬̱̬͖͕͈͓̬͚̟͖̥̜̼̞̞̣̳͈̹̱̥̥̼̲̦͙̞̫̣̜̜͈̩͙͍͙͔̼̫̭͇̱̯̣͈̠̟̥̗͈̫̺̱͚̼̻͎̳̭͖͚̖̘̝̖̙͈̺̼̮̙̙̜̖͓͉͖̭͈̺̺̻̟̣͚̰̪̰͌̏̔̎̍̽̀̈́̅̆̈́͌͗̂͋̅͗̐̌̄̉͆̌̔̀̓͒̐͊̓͐͋̾̿̌͑̄̒̔͊̈́̄̈͂̐̄͛̊͂̉̀̈̈̂̿̓̋͑̓̅͆̍̎̀͐͆͌̚̚͘̚̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͠ͅͅͅi̶̡̨̡̢̧̧̨̢̛̱̰̩̻̥̺͈̫̙̦͇̣̞̩̖̭̙̗̝̜̩̣̜̻̞͎̰͙͇̞̟̝̞͉̣̤̬͔̲̤̬̫̜̙̤̟̮͇̥͇̜͍̭̠̱͇̳͓̞̪̘̝̰̳͓̠̲͖̥̖̪̤̠̤̜̦̫̗̤̬̟͎̭̲̯̗̫̰̩̟͔̞̣͇͕̱͕̺̠̳̼͆̈̂͗̀͋̂̍̎̀̇̎͗͑͒̎͂̔̽̀͒͆̽̈́̋̆̈́̈̄̊́́͋͋̑͛͊͋͋́̎̐́͌̏̊́͒̅͛̽̃̓̏̉̉̓̍̃͘̚͘͘̚̕͜͠͠͝͠ͅͅͅơ̷̧̢̡̢̧̧̡̛̛̛̛̟͈͈͈̳̠̞̥͕̦̯̳͈͓͙̲̜̲̝̱͈͓̮̙̱̮̼̗̝̞͍͍͙̰̻̩͓̺̺͉̦͍̣̱̲̲̹̱̼̥̜͎͎͖̜̼̺̮̮̫͈̜̫̼̦̫̜̤͍̱̠̻̼͔̺̞͉̘̤̖̹̯͍͚͎̺̯͇̪̦̰̰̪̽̏̏͑̊̀̾͌̆̄̐̃̾̌͌̍̓̈͋̌͗͗̒̑͆̿̌͊͛̍͌̏̇̌̾̌̈́̌͗̌̓̀̔͌̍͒͂͑̍͑͗͒̓̊̀͆͛̓̑̒̎͊̿́͋̐͐͋̓̋͘͘̕̕͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͠͠͝͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅu̷̢̡̧̧̝̗͍̤̣̰̹͕͓̼͉͉͇̘̭͍͖̰͉̣̝̗̭̜͎̦̓͆̂͑̑͐̿̋͛̎͂̋̂̾̍̈́͐͛̈́̿̂̓̆̐͋͗͌͘͜ͅͅs̷̨̧̡̨̡̛̛̛̜͔͎̣̟̖̫͚̙̲̹̳̖̗͖̰̙̗̤̜̹̜̜͓̪̫̓̿̈́̐̉̋̏͊̇͊̍̓̓̾̈́͐̅͆̏̈̑̋̔̃̒̑̋̾͆̆͂̽̍͒̈́͋̑́̒̉̈͂̎̓̈́̆̓͗̂̌͛̓̒̽͆̂͋̑̿̈́̒̂̈́̆̇͆́́̊̄̍̉͒͗̈́͛̌́̌̀͑̍̎̂̚̚̕͘͝͝͝͠ͅļ̷̧̡̛̛̛̣̯͙̹͉̥̩͇͍͚͙͚̣̘̗̣̞̳̙͓̳̣̗̩̬̟̱̼̞̤̦̼͚̥̰̗̦̱̫̘͈͇̲̺͖̠̣͇̼͓͚͚̫͔̝̮̟͓͖͚̲̩͔͍̩͖̫̄̿͊̉͂̆͋̂̀̀̈́͌̒͐͑́̄̅̈́̀̾͒̔̇͐͆̇̀̅̉̒́̎̀̾͌̄̈̊̓̔̿̐̂̑̂͌͂̀̑͐͋͆̅̈́̀̓̀̈͋̓̆͌̓̏͑́̿͊͋́̀̾̾͗͐̓͆͂͒̃͆̊̈́̊͛͑͋͗̀̓͋͂̄͌̈́̿̏͋͆̍͛̀̿̄̊̇̋̈́̊̈́̔͂̓́́̚͘̚͘̕͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝ͅy̸̨̢͉̜͙̻̪͖͇̖̖̗̣̻̞̘̫̳̞̩̣̟̦͉̘̜͓̪̟̗̜̝̖̞͓̥̟͉͍̠͛̏̃̿͗̅̍͑͆̇̐̉̿̚̕͘͝ͅͅ,̸̢̢̡̨̢̧̢̡̢̡̢̢̼̘͙̲̩̜̹̪̼̞̜̙̯̱͖͉̯͉̭̠̱̮̮͈̥̞͉̮͍̰̥̥̯͔̬̘͕̫̳̖̗̣̣̳̱̩̪̤̖͇̗̞͇̰͇̗̝̣̪͕͍͓̤͈̥̜̜͓͇͓̪̪͇̩̗̞̯͔͚̦̬̮̱̰̭̙̣̺͙͔̍̉͊̌́̄̂͌̓͌̓̍̆͊̓̍͌̂͆͒̊̍̒̑̔͂͗͒͂̓̉̈͋͐͆̿̀̾̆̂͐̐̒̉̀̄̎̀͑̓̈͆̍͌͒̈́́̕͘͘̕͜͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅ ̶̨̧̛̛̛̳̻̻̟͈̲͓͍̠̭̰̫̻͎̲̞͍͉͉̣̝͇̞̣̯͔̹͚̭͖̩̳̜͔̣̹͚̘͇̟̦̱͓͖͎̟̝͉̼̹̹̼̟̲̳͍͉͉͖̺̥̬̠̹̞̟̗͔̘̺̼̜̙̖̙̹̺̖̞̲̬͍̭͕̗̙̩̜̪͂̒̊̓̏̀͆̎̿͗̀͛̅̑̒̋̑̃̏͂͋̓̀̅͌̑̎̏̑̓̔̊̔͂̈́͆̊̎̈́͐̋͑̂̈̍̋͛͋̒̾̃̂̉̽͂̊̍̅̀̊̓̐̇́̔͋͒̈́̆̎̓͒̅̾͛͊̀͊͑̔́̅̃͌̋̅̏͋̈́̉̇͑͐͛́̓͐̀͘̚͘̚̕̕̕̕̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝ͅt̵̡̨̡̢̢̡̨̢̨̨̛̞̥̫̯̰̫͍̤͕̞͇͔̬͔̘̳̥͍̝̼̫͓̩͔̫̪͈̖̬̭̠̰̻͕̞̼͖̦̘͍̗̥̫̠͇̜̳͍̥̖̹̤̦̤̮̲̞̗͇͕̭̱͚̟͉̫̺̥̰̘̰̻̘̬̻̭̺͚̜̠͈̯̫̻͕̞̹̳͖̻̻͎̣̳̻̺̩͕̰̖̩̼͌̍̇͌̒̅̎͊̐̆̎͗̅̆̈́͂́͗̎͐͋̍̊͌͑́͒̃́̈́̓̅̏͌́̓̋̽̈͑̌͑̂͛͒͑̿̾̇̓̌͌͆̃̋̂͐̆̃͛̓̇̈͐͆̏̉͋̐̏̓̓́͗̂͛̀͊́͐͒̄̈̽̈̓̀̕̕̚͘͘̕͜͝͝ͅh̵̨̲̯̥̬̟̩̲̩̦̭̳̮͚̬͓͎̯̦̙̫̘̪̖̣̼̬͊́̄̀͌͛̂̍̓̐̈́̌͊͐͌̈́̐̆̈́̎͋̈́̓̇͒͋̈́̀̉͒̽͆͛̉͒́͂̔́̅̒̈͑̀͜ͅi̷̢̡̢̨̢̨̡̛̫͍̼̭̫̪̻͚̥͖̳̬̥̯͈̼̱̳͉͖̬͈̮͓̙͇̠̱̩̟͕̝̺̦͈̼̻̮͕̱͚͚͎̟̱͉͈̦̼̿̈́͂̆͋͑́̎͒́́̃̓̽̅̄̄̎̎̐͐̊̅̌̄̎͗̂̀͑̇̂̄́͌̃͊͛͛̓̍͂͋̍̀̋̎́̔̾͛͑̑́̀̇͑͑͐͌̎͐͋̓̆͋̆̈́͒͒̌̓̑̾̃͊́͊̄͗̈̈̐̈́̔̌́̅̉̽̉̑̒̈́̇͛͐̓̄͐̽̀͛̔͊͂̈́̃̚͘̕͘͘̕͘̕̕̚͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͝ͅͅş̸̧̨̡̡̧̛̪̠̪̙̯͔͓̣̘͉̼̪̮͕̮̤̤̞̩̟̣̫̹̖̺̘̗͖̱̳̳͕̼̥̙̺̳͕̱̖͖̦̮̪͚͔̲̤͔͍̘̰͑̀̈́́͌̀͌̐̏͑̎̌̑̚͝͝ ̷̡̨̡̧̨̢̡̧̨̡̧̧̨̡̛̛͙̠̖͇̳͕̤͓̫̜͖̲̯̙͓̣͍̤̫̥̭̥̜̰̘͉̳̟͔̖̖͇̙̤͉̖̜̯̮̭̯̖͚̜͖̙̥͕̥̠̲̮͖̝̝̟͙͍͚͇̤͍̪͕̦̺̲̤͔̱͈͔̙͔̜̰̙̞͍̮̥͖̹̼̤̖̰̯͊́̍́͋̑̄̍̿̄̉̑͆̀̐̊͋̉͐͌͗̈̄͗̂̀̏͗͗̋͐͐̆̈̂͐͆̓̒͒̀̐̒̐̂̈́̒̈́͗͒͆̃͆͋̍̉̐͒́̽́̅̆̈́͛̈́͋͋̇̇̑̇̑͌̏̅̋̎̾̒̂̄̎̅̎͗̇͐̉̂̽͌̈́́́̐̅͂̑͗̑̂̅̆̄̅̐̂͋̎̃́̑͒̃̌͗̈́̽͐͑̈́̃́̊͛́̚͘̚͘̚͘͘͘̕̚͜͝͠͠͝͝͠͠͠͠͝͠͝ͅͅi̷̢̨̧̡̨̢̛͙̝̘̦̥͙͖͇̯͇̜̹̙̻̪̬͚͚͔̱̗͈͓̬̳͎̯̭̝̪̜̱̥̠͎̙̲̱̦͉̘͔͓̜̱̯̯̠̓̇͆̐͗͌͂̊͒̈́́̄̌̓͆̿͊̽̄̾͛̀͋̽́̉̽̆̓̈́̀͒͛͑͛̌͐̽̈́̆͂̽̀͒̅̌͌̚̚̚̚̚͜͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝ͅş̶̨̜̤͚̖͍͍͕͍̬̦̼̟̳͔̺͓͈̦̘̮̺̣̤̞̫͎͎̗̘̻̝͈͔̗̱̤͇͈͖̙̰̳͎̲̣̰̭͆͑̒͆̽͑́̉̈̈́̋͋̓̋͌͑̄͐͌͌̎̌͗̉͜͝͝ͅ ̸̧̢̢̨̢̛͔͉̗͓͙̘̙̘͖͉̯͖͍̰͙̣̪̺̹͕̥̯̰̝̞͔͇͓̻̗̖͙̜̪̥̯͔̣̟̞̖͎̟̣̖̟̟̤̩̭͎̲͔̭͉͙̪̳͉̳̺̏̔͑̌̒̔̓̾͑̉̇̐̋̉̃̓͂̌̃̾̊̿͌̑̓̿̿̆̑́̔̂͐̽̿́̈̔͋̆͋̔̈́̈́̎̈́͋̅͐̍̓̃̆̅̊̓̓͒̒̊̃̒͆̆̂͒̒̉́̊͛̌͊̽̐͛̋̉́̅̾̉̉́͊͒͌̆̿̈̎̈́̄́͆̓̉̎̇̎̓́̇̍͑̑̕̚̕̕̚̕͘̚̚͜͜͠͝͝͝͠͝ą̴̡̧̧̡̛̛̛̛̰̟̙̭̙͈̟̮̖̮͉̹̰̺̘̺̪̯̗̜̞̹̪͕̤̻͉̖̟͚͎͎̱̤̥̹̜̩̫̹̔̊̈͗̂̂̃͒͋̎̈́̀̅͌̅͆͆͗́͗̅̈́̅͂̊̽̌͛͊͐̀̏̔̀͆̄̈́͒̓͑̈́̑̈́̍̓͊̏͂̍̍̌̀̕͠͝ ̴̧̡̡̛̥͎̝͔̖͉̲͙̝̳̦̟͖͍͎̞̥͙͕͈̮͍̞͕͚̖̠̥̘̯͕̌̀́̾͋͆̆̃͋́͒͗̽̆̊̌̀͂̍͊̋͛̉̅̓̌̋̇̑̒̎̎̚̚͘͠͝͝ͅͅp̵̡̨̡̡̢̡̛͙̬͎̦̜͚̩̰̝̹͎̺͉͙̩̪̲͈͉̺̣͓̘̟̱̹͈̺̹̞͉̤̘͖̰̻͇͚͉͔̙͙̦̭͎͖̙̩̪̱̘̼̠͉̳̱̟̼͇͇̭͓͔̪̟̪͇̙͕̣̦̜͉̤̳̜͔̦̘̮̲͇̱̘͚͍̖͉͓̙̳͎̟͕̬̫͓̙̥͇̮̮̲̥̦̯͕̻̥̼͇̱͕͔̻̼̮̫̰̫̗̼̟̯̯̠̝͔̦̘̻̗̥͉̖̪͈̉͐͒͂̄̔̄͗̓̐̒̇͛̄͛̒̐̈́̌̿̑̓̐͐̈͗̀̅̅̏̒͑̌͌̈́͋͛͗̓̓̔̔̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͝ͅr̴̨̢̢̢̧̢̢̢̨̨̧̢̨̡̢̡̛̛̭̰̫̠̰̙͙͓̤̖̣̝̠̱͍̞͙̥̩̟̥͙̤̳̳͔̼̘͖͓̙̰̤̬̬̪̼̩͚̫̩̲̲̝̠̠̭̥̬̠͕̘̳̭̱̯͕̺̯̻̗͈̙̺̜͍͈̳̱̟͕͈̰̖͙̻̝̫̠̺̩̳̖̲͕̪͚̰͕̠̪̟̹͈̩͛͛́̓̊̾͑͒͌̈́̃͗̿͗̔̀̌̉͋̓͌̎̄̄̌̾̓͒͛͋́̒̍̋̈́͂̌̀͛̂͘͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅơ̴̡̡̧̢̡̨̢̡̡̢̨̢̺̙͚̣͖̤̱̦̫̠̭̬̥̟̜͈̗̻̻̗̝̫̮̟̬͈͍̙͖̠̠̮͎͈͇̙̫̪̺̱͎̝͇͉͖̻̟̦̬̘̬̰̰̖͈͍̥̰͉̲̝̭͈̟̭̪̼̪͈͉͈̺͇͚͕̝̱̬̙͚̳̩͋̆͐̎͛͆̈́̏͆̍̈́̏̅̆̈́͒͋͊̓͊͆̎̋̌̒̎͗͋̂̂͋̂̔̆̈́̍̎͆͌̊̐̓̅̈́͌̓̾̃̋̓̆̚͘̕̚͘͘͜͠͠ͅͅb̷̧̧̧̨̢̛̛̩̞̳͈̟̫̞̳̤̺̝͓̩̗͔͉̦͍̜̪͍͈̫̠͓̫̳̩̲̫̞̲̙̻̤̣̮̱͕̟̻̦̰͇̘̜̓̑̌̃͑̓̊̐̓͑͊͗̒̑̆̇̇͌͌̀̅̐̀̔͜ͅͅl̵̡̧̡̛̛͚̠̳̙̞̤͉̻̳̤͚̩̠̻͔̫̔̓́́̊́̂̄̒͛̌͑̋̀͑͑͑̔̀͛̋͊́̿͋̋́̾̃̓͑̒̀́̾͛̔̎̾̆̈͗̽̀̽̓̀̈́̽̎́̒̄̀̈̓̑́̆̄̈́̂͐̽̒̒͋̈́̊̓̂̀́̏̌̓̏́̎̋͗̀̅̂͒͘̕̚̕͘̕͘͘͜͝͝͝͝͝ę̵̢̢̡̧̡̡̢̢̧̡̨̡̢͕̯̖̰̬̟̻̳̳̞͓̠̠̯̟̳̞̦̤̣̭̼͖̤̩̭̦̪͉̰̠͖̻̣̯̼͙̖̹͚͈͙͇͔̦̰̲̘͉͇̘̟̖̹̥͔͉̣͓̝̹͇̻͙̦̳͉͕̲̙̮̙̘͖͔͚̮̻͙̣͉̣̲̼̰̲̳̰̪͕̤͎̼̝̣̭̻̯̮̱̯̋̾̍̂̊̓̋̊̈́͜͜͜͝͝ͅͅͅm̸̨̢̧̡̡̨̢̡̨̧̡̢̡̢͚̣̳̪̝̲̝̳͙̩̫͔̤͈̰̟̖͎̰̬̠̼̯͓͉͈̯̖̜̳͓͚̫̖̩͉͚̰̳͖̟̺̝̥̜̭̯̞̼̗͓̲̫͔̩͕̳͙̖̮̲̣͈̞̭͕̮̻̭̻͍̩͉̫͙̳̰̬̦̣͕̜̺̳̼̠͙̣̪͙̳̗͚̘͉̬͇̜͇̭̭̭̝̫̮̗̞̠̤͎͓̍͗͆͌̐̂̔̏̽̌̊̓̀̇̀̏̒͆̇̒̉͐̾͛̽́̓͜͝ͅͅ.̶̢̡̡̢̧̛̛̯͕͚̩̞̻̫̠̲̞͍̥̥̘̩͇̣̝̭̲͈͎͈̲͕̲̩̜̼̣̳̣̲̣̞̣̜̝̼̞͕͍̹͍̤̟̘̱̬̼̳̀̾͂̀̔́̈́̊͌͂̀̿̄̉̔̒̎̋̈̈̈́̀̐̆̀̓̈́̓͂̽̎̽̽̀̅̑̍̾͑̾̅̒̎͐̈́̅͐̽́͒̄̈́̔̾̐͛̀̈̀͑̀̓̂͂̃̈́̔͆̿͒͗̎͐͑̇̒̂̃̓́̽̏̐̌̀̏͒̍̓͋̀̎̈̒̅̇̀̿̾̈͛̄̇̂̐͌̽̎̂̈̄̈́͂͑̀̕̚̚͘͘͘̕̕͜͜͜͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝ͅͅ

Comment: Where did all of the comments go?

Comment: Probably cleaned up by a mod. I think it would've been better if they're moved to chat instead, but that's the mod's decision.

Comment: @41686d6564 Strange, some of them were very relevant to this post and important to understanding it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what repeatedly editing this post is going to do except induce another downvote.  I've only ever seen Zalgo in the Sandbox, which usually looks crazy, and rene [already explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363379/798831) pretty well that there are plenty of ways to get rid of accidental mishaps.  In my humble opinion, this would be a waste of developer time to fix a problem that exists (or seems to) on only one post:  The Sandbox.

Comment: @Ollie This would make it harder to flag a post posted elsewhere, and it shouldn't be difficult to flag something.

Comment: @Anonymous Give one good example of this

Comment: @Nai54 Of a spam post being flagged?  How can I do that?  There's no way to know how many times people had difficulty with this.

Comment: @Anonymous That's where the keyboard shortcuts come in.  Have you seen an example of this being abused *outside* of the Sandbox?

Comment: @Anonymous What Ollie said

Comment: @Ollie No, I can't view deleted posts.

Comment: @Anonymous No, before deletion

Comment: @Anonymous apologies, I meant before it was deleted.  It'll still be in the timeline if it was edited out.

Comment: @Ollie Not if it's redacted.

Comment: Is Zalgo ever redacted?

Comment: @Mast Why wouldn't it be?  It would make the edit history less confusing and more readable.

Comment: That's not the purpose of redactions. Redactions are for sensitive information we really don't want to stay visible in an edit history, like personal information and other things that can get either the company or users in legal trouble.

Comment: Did you note that the Zalgo text can be clicked through?

Comment: @Mast But not seen through, you'd have to guess where the right buttons are.  With comments, you could even flag the wrong one.

Comment: Hardly. Once you've clicked it a hundred times, you know it by rote. But I can understand fresher users having trouble with it, sure.

Comment: @Mast There might not be a way to tell which comment is the one with Zalgo, you might accidentally flag the one under or above it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1573/discussion-between-anonymous-and-mast).

Answer (score 16):

No.

Let's not spend the limited development resources to "fix" something that is basically abuse of the system.

There are plenty of options available already to overcome any accidental Zalgo mishaps:

- **edit** (visit `[site]/posts/{id}/edit` in case the edit link is "covered",
   or use keyboard shortcut <kbd>E</kbd>);
- **down vote;**
- **flag** (any post with a custom flag, in case the flag link is "covered"`, 
  or use keyboard shortcut <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>);
- user suspension.

And in case you argue that you have a valid use case for Zalgo in posts that can't be handled within the current system boundaries: Show me one.

None of the posts on the network about [Zalgo](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=zalgo&page=1) need an *extraneous amount* (your words) to demonstrate what the post is about. We don't need this feature nor does it need fixing.

Comment: Well one solution is to edit it out, and suspend the user if they keep doing it. Its a classic "Doctor, it hurts when I poke myself in the eye"

Comment: In the Formatting Sandbox, Zalgo is acceptable but it can be annoying (especially in the comments).  If this were fixed, it would be a whole lot less annoying.

Comment: @Anonymous it is not acceptable in the formatting sandbox either. Flag comments and edit posts that make the effective usage of the sandbox impossible.

Comment: @rene It is if it only slightly goes out of the post box (with comments, it is nearly impossible to not have it have it spill out slightly).

Comment: I think this answer missed the point of the question, which is the zalgo text covers the flag or edit links making them hard to find. And if you just downvote, it still covers other answers. Not saying I agree with this or not. The OP isn't saying there is a valid use case for zalgo text.